# transform a column of array of string in pyspark to multiple rows in one column

Tags: hive, pyspark

I would like to transform a table with a column as array of strings on databricks pyspark.

my table:

```
 id         values  (array<string>)
 rgf        ['vwervfrev', 'fweccf', 'tuyhert']
 rty        ['evvverws', 'ilonmunt', 'cedcrhb']
```

What I need:

```
 id         values
 rdf        'vwervfrev'
 rdf        'fweccf'
 rdf        'tuyhert'
 rty        'evvverws'
 rty        'ilonmunt'
 rty        'cedcrhb'
```

I am not sure how to do the transformation ?

thanks

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the explode function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col

new_df = df.withColumn("values", explode(col("values")))
new_df.show()
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#explode